# Qt style sheet: customize subcontrol filtered by parent's selector

Tags: qt, user-interface, qtstylesheets

I want to cusomize **QToolButton** class so it won't show arrow subcontrol when button has a context menu. But I need to apply this style sheet only for buttons with **QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup** popup mode. How to do it properly? I have tried the following sheet:

`QToolButton[popupMode != "1"]::menu-indicator {image: none}`

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

This solution what worked for me. I used a dynamic Property (bool) in the Designer to convert a `Check Box` into an `Indicator Lamp`.

```
QCheckBox[indicator=true]::indicator::checked { image: url(:themes_22x22/Icons_oxygen22x22/emblems/emblem-important.png);} 
QCheckBox[indicator=true]::indicator::unchecked { image: url(:themes_22x22/Icons_oxygen22x22/status/user-online.png);}
```